# nginx chain reaction when using try_files when server returns status code 500 results in double submission

Tags: nginx

following config:

```
 location ~ /{
        try_files /$uri /$uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

this will try several things when the server returns 500. It will walk down the chain and try the next thing. But: as it is a form that is failing, the form is resubmitted, and the things that happen until the faulty code, happen thus twice. Is there a way to only try one thing with `try_files` or an alternative to `try_files`?

using `=500` at the end is not a solution, because it will not show the error page.

**EDIT** I add the complete server block.

I have a bit a complex setup with wordpress and laravel. Wordpress is at home in the main folder, whereas all calls to `caup_api` and subfolders need to go to the laravel installation. Thus i have a softlink
`caup_api -> ./caup_laravel/public/`

that is so i can use all calls normally made the caup_api folder are sent directly to laravel and not processed by wordpress. The problematic config is the one with `caup_api`

```
server {
    listen 80;

 server_name dev.myapp.org;

     root /var/www/html/dev.myapp.org/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_lukas23.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_lukas23.com.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /apple-touch-icon.png { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }


location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 500 501 502 503 = @fallback;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        ##fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9900;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        ##fastcgi_pass hhvm;
    }
    location @fallback {
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        ##fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9900;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        ##fastcgi_pass jcrdev;
    }
    location ~* .(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { expires 1d; }

   location ~ /caup_api {
        try_files /caup_api/$uri /caup_api/$uri/ /caup_api/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ /causes {
        try_files /caup_api/$uri /caup_api/$uri/ /caup_api/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause your code to run twice. Did you omit something from your question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is nginx behaviour. I actually changed the code to return, on the exact same error case, status code 200. The calls are not done twice. Let me tell you again what I suspect: `try_files` tries to send the post data to `/$uri` this returns 500, thus it sends it to `/$uri/` both cases, call exactly the same code, the same code entry, the exact same code runs again, returning again 500. I only have this, when the app returns 500, when it does not, it does not run twice.

Comment: Err, `try_files` doesn't work like that. If the first one returns a 500, then nginx returns a 500. It does not keep going. The only circumstance in which it would keep going is if the one it tried did not exist at all. Something else is going on here. So it's important that you show the complete `server` block.

Comment: Yes, the answer was in the complete `server` block.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running twice because you explicitly asked for it to be run twice.

First, `try_files` finds your URL, or more specifically it *doesn't* find your URL, and so it runs your PHP script because you ended it with `/index.php?...`. This causes nginx to execute your script using the directives within `location ~ \.php$`.

When this returns a 500 error, the `error_page 500 ...` directive in that `location` kicks in. This tells nginx to deliver a specific document instead of its own internal 500 error page. In your case, it tells nginx to hit the `@fallback` location, which has the effect of calling your PHP code again.

To resolve the problem, you need to think more carefully about what you want to happen when a 500 error occurs in your program, or perhaps better yet, not return 500 errors.

Comment: or i can just remove the fallback portion of it? i mean the configuration was copied from somewhere a long time ago and as you can tell, i am a nginx config amateur. I can just delete the entire line with error_page i guess? and returning 500 is of course always an accident. But while developing it happens a lot. And double execution leads to not understanding the 500 code any longer

Comment: I don't see any good reason for that, unless you have some specific PHP script you want to run. The example nginx configuration serves a static HTML page on 50x errors.

Comment: so removing the fallback is not an option and just display the normal page, even on error, avoiding the double call? instead have the framework return 200 even if it is a 500?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: it is simple, I don't want to use a fallback. In case of error, just display the page that caused the error.

Comment: OK, sure, you can do that.

Comment: so I remove the fallback and the error_page definition and thats it?